# Use insertUI method to create different shiny widgets

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which the user may select between one or more column names from the  data frame.

```
name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
value1<-c(2,4,6)
add<-c("SDF","GHK","FGH")
value2<-c(3,4,5)
dt<-data.frame(name,value1,add,value2)
```

Then for every selection he makes the relative `pickerInput()` may be displayed below. Maybe I could use `if` for every case but the issue is that my real dataset may be much bigger and has different column names every time so Im looking for a way to instantly connect the `pickerInput()` selected name with the creation of the relative `pickerInput()` which will include the column values. For example if someone select all 4 column names 4 `pickerInput()` should be created with the relative column name as label.

My method is the `insertUI` method but I have to find a way to create widget with different choices and label every time and also remove it when de-select the relative value of the 1st `pickerInput()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# ui object
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput(
                inputId = "p1",
                label = "Select Column headers",
                choices = colnames( dt),
                multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
            )

            
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$p1, {
        insertUI(
            selector = "#p1",
            where = "afterEnd",
            ui = pickerInput(
                inputId = #The colname of selected column
                    ,
                label = #The colname of selected column
                    ,
                choices = #all rows of selected column
                    ,
                multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
            )
        )
    })

    
    
    
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like using `lapply` to create input element in shiny, because when you add an element, the input UIs for the already existing (selected) inputs get overwritten, and so everything is set back to the defaults and previously chosen values for these inputs get lost.

You can pair `insertUI` with `removeUI` and a variable to keep track of the previously selected columns. Then you can dynamically add/remove UI elements and keep the other inputs unchanged.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
value1<-c(2,4,6)
add<-c("SDF","GHK","FGH")
value2<-c(3,4,5)
dt<-data.frame(name,value1,add,value2)

# ui object
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "Select Column headers",
        choices = colnames( dt),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      tags$div(id = "add_ui_here")
      
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # store currently selected columns
  selected_columns <- c()
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
    
    # determine pickerInputs to remove
    input_remove <- !selected_columns %in% input$p1
    input_remove <- selected_columns[input_remove]
    
    # remove inputs
    if (!is.null(input_remove) && length(input_remove) > 0) {
      for (input_element in input_remove) {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", input_element, "_remove_id"))
      }
    }
    
    # determine pickerInputs to add
    input_add <- !input$p1 %in% selected_columns
    input_add <- input$p1[input_add]
    
    # add inputs
    if (length(input_add) > 0) {
      for (input_element in input_add) {
        insertUI(
          selector = "#add_ui_here",
          where = "afterEnd",
          ui = tags$div(id = paste0(input_element, "_remove_id"),
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = input_element
                          ,
                          label = input_element
                          ,
                          choices = dt[, input_element]
                          ,
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
                        ))
        )
      }
    }
    
    # update the currently stored column variable
    selected_columns <<- input$p1
  },
  ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  
  
  
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've wrapped the inserted `pickerInputs` in a `div`, so it's easier to remove them. Also, you need to set `ignoreNULL = FALSE` for the observer, so that it also get triggered if all elements get deselected.

Comment: I like your answer .This is a similar here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764205/use-insertui-to-create-different-kind-of-shiny-widgets

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` with `renderUI` instead of `insertUI`

```
name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
value1<-c(2,4,6)
add<-c("SDF","GHK","FGH")
value2<-c(3,4,5)
#Add stringsAsFactor=F to correctly display options of name and add
dt<-data.frame(name,value1,add,value2,stringsAsFactors = F)

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# ui object
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "Select Column headers",
        choices = colnames( dt),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
#Add the output for new pickers
      uiOutput("pickers")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$p1, {
#Create the new pickers 
    output$pickers<-renderUI({
      
      div(lapply(input$p1, function(x){
        pickerInput(
          inputId = x#The colname of selected column
            ,
          label = x #The colname of selected column
            ,
          choices = dt[,x]#all rows of selected column
            ,
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
        )
      }))
    })
  })
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I like your answer .This is a similar here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764205/use-insertui-to-create-different-kind-of-shiny-widgets

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to generate the `pickerInput` list and to render it using `tagList` in `renderUI`:

```
# Data
name<-c("John","Jack","Bill")
value1<-c(2,4,6)
add<-c("SDF","GHK","FGH")
value2<-c(3,4,5)
dt<-data.frame(name,value1,add,value2)


# App
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# ui object
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("pickers")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output) {
  pickers <- colnames(dt)
  output$pickers <- renderUI({
    l <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(pickers)) {
       l[[i]] <- pickerInput(pickers[i],pickers[i],dt[[pickers[i]]])
    }
    tagList(l)
   })

}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]