# How can I reactively update the active menuItem in a Shiny app using `renderUI`?

Tags: r, shiny, bs4dash

I am building a shiny app that dynamically creates reactive `bs4Box` elements from a data frame. I want to make those boxes clickable by the user so that automatic redirection to a different menuItem occurs. I have read and followed similar previous SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238427/how-to-create-dynamic-number-of-observeevent-in-shiny) or [this issue](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/86) without success. A JavaScript solution [like this one](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/50#issuecomment-530699434) could also work?

Here's my attempt so far using the `updatebs4ControlbarMenu` function:

```r
library(shiny)
#> Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(shinyWidgets)
#> Warning: package 'shinyWidgets' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(bs4Dash)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'bs4Dash'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     column, tabPanel, tabsetPanel, updateTabsetPanel
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3

shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_collapsed = TRUE,
    enable_preloader = FALSE,
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(skin = "dark"),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(
      inputId = "sidebarState",
      bs4SidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebr",
        bs4SidebarMenuItem(
          "Tab 1",
          tabName = "tab1"
        ),
        bs4SidebarMenuItem(
          "Tab 2",
          tabName = "tab2"
        )
      )
    ),
    
    bs4DashBody(
      bs4TabItems(
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          h1("Welcome!"),
          fluidRow(
            pickerInput(
              inputId = "car",
              label = "Car", 
              choices = row.names(mtcars),
              selected = head(row.names(mtcars), 3),
              multiple = TRUE,
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = TRUE)
            ),
            pickerInput(
              inputId = "gear",
              label = "Gear", 
              choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
              selected = unique(mtcars$gear),
              multiple = TRUE,
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = TRUE)
            )
          ),
          
          fluidRow(
            column(6,
                   uiOutput("uiboxes")
            )
          )
        ),
        
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab2",
          h4("Yuhuuu! You've been directed automatically in Tab 2!")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    submtcars <- reactive({
      req(input$car, input$gear)
      mtcars %>% 
        mutate(
          carnames = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
        filter(
          carnames %in% input$car &
            gear %in% input$gear
        )
    })
    
    
    observeEvent( submtcars(), {
      
      output$uiboxes <- renderUI({
        n_ex <- nrow(submtcars())
        lapply(1:n_ex, FUN = function(j) {
          print(paste("j is ", j))
          bs4Box(
            title = submtcars()$carnames[j],
            width = 12,
            str_c("Number of gears:", submtcars()$gear[j]),
            
            btnID <- paste0("btnID", j),
            
            print(btnID),
            fluidRow(
              column(
                2,
                actionBttn(
                  inputId = btnID,
                  icon("search-plus")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        })
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent( input$btnID , {
      updatebs4ControlbarMenu(
        session,
        inputId = "sidebr",
        selected = "tab2"
      )
      
    })
  }
)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5851
#> [1] "j is  1"
#> [1] "btnID1"
#> [1] "j is  2"
#> [1] "btnID2"
#> [1] "j is  3"
#> [1] "btnID3"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you set up the `observeEvent`. You only register one observer that listens to `input$btnID`. However, `btnID` is only a variable in which you define the different IDs for the action buttons (in your case "btnID1" to "btnID3". Therefore, you must register `observeEvent`s with these IDs. For this, you can use `lapply` again as in my solution below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bs4Dash)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
    controlbar_collapsed = TRUE,
    enable_preloader = FALSE,
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(skin = "dark"),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(
      inputId = "sidebarState",
      bs4SidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebr",
        bs4SidebarMenuItem(
          "Tab 1",
          tabName = "tab1"
        ),
        bs4SidebarMenuItem(
          "Tab 2",
          tabName = "tab2"
        )
      )
    ),
    
    bs4DashBody(
      bs4TabItems(
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          h1("Welcome!"),
          fluidRow(
            pickerInput(
              inputId = "car",
              label = "Car", 
              choices = row.names(mtcars),
              selected = head(row.names(mtcars), 3),
              multiple = TRUE,
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = TRUE)
            ),
            pickerInput(
              inputId = "gear",
              label = "Gear", 
              choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
              selected = unique(mtcars$gear),
              multiple = TRUE,
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = TRUE)
            )
          ),
          
          fluidRow(
            column(6,
                   uiOutput("uiboxes")
            )
          )
        ),
        
        bs4TabItem(
          tabName = "tab2",
          h4("Yuhuuu! You've been directed automatically in Tab 2!")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    submtcars <- reactive({
      req(input$car, input$gear)
      mtcars %>% 
        mutate(
          carnames = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
        filter(
          carnames %in% input$car &
            gear %in% input$gear
        )
    })
    
    
    observeEvent( submtcars(), {
      n_ex <- nrow(submtcars())
      output$uiboxes <- renderUI({
        
        lapply(1:n_ex, FUN = function(j) {
          print(paste("j is ", j))
          bs4Box(
            title = submtcars()$carnames[j],
            width = 12,
            str_c("Number of gears:", submtcars()$gear[j]),
            
            btnID <- paste0("btnID", j),
            
            print(btnID),
            fluidRow(
              column(
                2,
                actionBttn(
                  inputId = btnID,
                  icon("search-plus")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        })
      })
      
      lapply(1:n_ex, function(j) {
        btnID <- paste0("btnID", j)
        observeEvent(input[[btnID]] , {
          updatebs4ControlbarMenu(
            session,
            inputId = "sidebr",
            selected = "tab2"
          )
        })
      })
    })
    
  }
)
```

However, I think that approaches with `lapply` and `renderUI` are not very good, as all the boxes get rendered anew if one of your inputs change, while maybe some boxes would stay the same. Therefore, I recommend an approach with `insertUI`/`removeUI`. Have a look at some of my older answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63758952/12647315

Comment: Thanks @starja. While it works, my app is modularized and I'm struggling to implement this solution as explained in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65262056/7375944